# Ребята и девчата

Tags: семантика, лексика

Можно ли употреблять слово "ребята" в отношении группы, состоящей из девочек и мальчиков?
Из одних девочек?

Интересует мнение носителей языка, а не словарные определения.

Я лично исхожу из того, что девчата - от девочка, ребята - от ребенок (любого пола), а для мальчиков надо бы "мальчата".

~~~ 
Непосредственным поводом для вопроса послужила свежая оговорка спортивного комментатора.

Комментатор назвал женскую сборную "наши ребята". Потом на мгновение задумался и сказал "девчата". Если бы не поправился, я бы и не обратил внимания, я вообще одним ухом телевизор "смотрел", сидючи за компьютером. После этого комментатор стал говорить "девчонки".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о детях - то слово **РЕБЯТА** употребляется и по отношению к группе мальчиков, и по отношению к смешанной группе. Если в классе или в группе одни девочки, то и обращаемся к ним "девочки". По крайней мере в моей практике и у моих коллег так.
Если речь идет о взрослых молодых людях, то в живой речи, по-моему, та же ситуация. А вот словари говорят по-другому: **ребята** - разг., собир. молодые люди, как правило, мужского пола; также обращение к нескольким молодым людям. Например: *Девки и молодые ребята становятся в две шеренги одна против другой, хлопают в ладоши и поют.* [М.Ю.Лермонтов, «Герой нашего времени»]. Как бы то ни было, как мне кажется, назвать чисто женский коллектив "ребятами" - ошибка. Это почувствовал даже комментатор, вряд ли глубоко вникающий в семантические тонкости произносимых им слов [или я плохо думаю о комментаторах :-)))].

Answer (score 2):

Интересно, что сказал спортивный комментатор. Мои мысли по поводу... Слово "ребята" в отношении группы, состоящей из девочек и мальчиков употребляется. Такое обращение можно услышать в школах. Это слово  в отношении группы, состоящей из одних девочек, я не слышала. Также оно является синонимом к слову "мальчики". У мужского пола приоритет :)) Об одном мальчике и одной девочке говорят "оба", как и о двух мальчиках. А если две девочки, уже "обе".

Answer (score 2):

Смешанную группу однозначно называем "ребята". Одних мальчиков - тоже. Если группа из девочек - не знаю , но резкого "против" не ощущаю. Был у мена класс - 20 девушек и два юноши. Конечно, я  говорила "ребята". А вот если эти двое юношей вдруг болели? Разве я говорила по-другому? Как? ДЕти? - нет, и на "девочки-девушки - барышни" - не переходила. И вообще, так я обращусь скорее на перемене (менее официальная обстановка). Мне кажется, слово *ребята* в таком случае как синоним слову *ученики* (но это слово для обращения не служит.)

Представлю себя девочкой. Иду гулять  с подружками. Скажу ли маме, что пошла гулять с ребятами? - НЕт, ни за что. С ребятами - это и с девочками,  и с мальчиками.

Так что из моего языкового опыта получилось, что  ребята - это 1. и мальчики, и девочки 2. мальчики 3. дети или молодые люди, объединенные  деятельностью

Кстати, я вспоминаю, что в детстве для меня *ребята* однозначно было синонимом слову *дети*, о значении "ребята"="мальчики" я узнала из кинофильмов, или из книг, или когда в Москву первый раз (в 8 лет) поехала и там играла  (сейчас точно уже не скажу), но не из своего окружения.

Answer (score 1):

И я, и я того же мнения. О группе девочек "ребята" не скажу. В детстве в лапту играла с ребятами, а в куклы - с девчонками. "Ребята"  - так обращались  офицеры русской армии к солдатам: "Ребята, не Москва ль за нами?"

Answer (score -2):

"ребята" можно использовать к молодым людям - исключительно к парням. А "ребятня" - собирательное существительное, используемое и к мальчикам, и к девочкам. Молодёжь: и девушки, и парни.

Comment: Интересно, а чем ваш ответ кому-то не понравился?  
Я как автор вопроса причин минусить не вижу.

Не могу сказать, что согласен с идеей об отношении исключительно к молодым людям, но возможно это явление определённой возрастной прослойки - тем и ценно.