# "Мысли по поводу"

Tags: грамотная-речь, уточнения

Инна в ответе на [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) (отличный, кстати, вопрос и история!) написала:

> Мои мысли по поводу...

Имела в виду она, очевидно, *мысли по **этому** поводу.* Также иногда встречаешь *мысли на тему.*

Скажите, это действительно вошло в язык? Можно так пропускать слово?

Answer (score 1):

Я часто встречаю это выражение как название сайта и что-то не задумывалась о его корректности. Видимо, сыгрывает современная тенденция языка к экономии средств. Вот раньше считалось речевой ошибкой употреблять предлог после как наречие, а сейчас маститые писатели пишут: "Это будет после, а пока..." Так что, видимо, всё корректно.

Есть мысли по поводу и без повода...
https://nsportal.ru/blog/obshcheobrazovatelnaya-tematika/all/2012/12/20/mysli-po-povodu-i-bez-povoda

Мысли по поводу и без  https://arinka-chan.livejournal.com/3532.html

http://wap.adomogarov.borda.ru/?1-0-0-00000001-000-10001-0

https://universal_ru_en.academic.ru/2371653/%D1%80%D0%B

https://kuklin-r.livejournal.com/2411.html

http://eggs.com.ua/humor.php?sid=662

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!